# how to fix "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector" after even installing mysql-connector?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-connector

i've an error in my code and it's "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector"

i'm using ubuntu 16.04 and i've already installed mysql-connector
even several times using commands for example:
-->sudo pip install mysql-connector
-->pip install mysql-connector-python

Comment: If you use Python3 you have to use `pip3` or `python3 -m pip install ...`

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: i've copy pasted the full error traceback, it's all i just get

Comment: Often there are multiple Python installations and it was installed for the wrong one.

Comment: so, any idea how to fix it?